# Betaflight with Mamba F405 MK2 stack 40A ESC's and XING-E 2207 motors problem

Tags: quadcopters, esc, dshot, bidirectional-dshot

I build a quad using Mamba F405 MK2 stack 40A ESC's and XING-E 2207 motors.

Here are some pictures of my configurations on Betaflight and BLHeli Configurator:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOr9L.jpg

Also video of issue in Reddit:

https://www.reddit.com/r/Multicopter/comments/inphxg/why_is_this_happening_with_my_motors/

I used to have two issues:

I set Bidirection Dshot with 4khz PID loop freq and because using F4 FC I had to change to Dshot300. Then when trying to set little bit the Throttle after arming the quad the motors suddently spin super mega fast (very dangerous).

When I arm the quad the motors start spinning even that I have set not to spin when armed.

What I did for the first issue is to remove bidirectional dshot. Seems that because the ESC only support Dshot 600 when I set Dshot 300 it start behaving pretty bad.

Any clue if using F4 flight controller I can use Dshot600 with bidirectional dshot?

Also any clue on how to solve the start spinning motors thing?

Thanks

Comment: Doesn't the BLHELI Configurator not work properly with BLHeli32 ESCs? I thought you had to use BLHELI_suite

Comment: No, for BLHeli_S you have to use BLHeli Configurator. There is no other way. :) But works pretty good.

Comment: Oh wait... have you flashed custom firmware to your BLHELI_S ESCs or are you running them stock with the latest official release?

Comment: Actually I downloaded the HEX file 16.73 for BLHeli_S and seems that fixed the issue. THe only issue pending is that my motors spin when armed at min throttle with Angle mode. I saw that pid_at_min_throttle was ON so I just set it to OFF and I will try today.

Comment: Well that shouldn't be working either... stock BLHELI_S firmware doesn't support bidirectional DSHOT.

Comment: Yes stock BLHELI_S doesnt support for 16.73 from Jazz works good. Well thats what I think. Dont know how to test that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have airmode enabled as a feature then the motors will spin on arm no matter what other settings you have.

It sounds to me like you may have accidentally set your ESC's to bi-directional in BL-heli configurator which is NOT the same as bi-directional DSHOT protocol.  Check out this video for explanation on the difference : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DXfAnCLr3q0&t=65s